# Inflate list view in a cardview recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview, cardview

I have a recyclerview contains a list of cardview ( 1 textview, 1 button to add and list which has a visibilty gone) so once the user press on the add button it takes him to another activity to do some job and once he save he should add an item inside the selected card listview and am stuck i have no idea how to do it in a onactivityresult to inflate an item of a specific card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bundle to send arguments to the activity and back. 
For example,
When the user clicks on an add button in the item in the RecyclerView.
your adapter knows the position. As a matter of fact, your onClick must be implemented in your adapter.
Send that position to the activity as putExtra before you startActvity.
And then before finish you can again do putExtra.

```
//Your onClick handler in the Adapter class
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position); //position in adapter
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);



//in the next activity before finish()
Intent intent = getIntent();
itnent.putExtra("position", position);
finish();

//in your previous activity 
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    String pos = data.getStringExtra("position");
    adapter.getItem(Integer.parseInt(pos));
}
```

Comment: And how you can add data to a listview  of a known adapter position?

Comment: so if you know the position then you can also get its View. once you have View, you can get its children. 
You can findViewById on that View

Comment: So on activity result i get the adapter position again and i call the listview and add an item to it? But i am worried how android is going to know that he should inflate for example the third cardview listview

Comment: the position you just passed will exactly update that position.

Comment: Can you please show me a code example inside an onactivity result trying to inflate a listview with a well known position to it ? Because once i inflate it does for everything